# Handle IActionResult in MVC6

Tags: asp.net-mvc, testing, asp.net-core-mvc

I build my first mvc6 api with :

https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/tutorials/first-web-api.html

I wanted to write test for it now but how can I cast a IActionResult which returns a JSON string to an Model(e.g User)

I get a error which says:

Cannot Convert IAction result to User ...

```
[HttpGet("{}")]
public IActionResult getUser()
{
  Benutzer benutzerData = _context.benutzer.FirstOrDefault<User>();

  return new ObjectResult(benutzerData);
}
```

and in my Test class :

```
  Benutzer user = _controller.getUser();
```

Comment: Ok i found a way with (ObjectResult) cast ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this

```
[HttpGet("{}")]
public IActionResult getUser()
{
  Benutzer benutzerData = _context.benutzer.FirstOrDefault<User>();

  return Ok(benutzerData);
}
```

you cannot store json string to model class object instead you can store it in string and you can pass the string to the model.And also use cannot call controller in model class